# django: how to control user access to web content with limited allowence per day?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have an online pricing website using django.

Now I want to restrict non-vip users to use my website to obtain price. For non-vip users, after login they can only use my web to get price only 3 times per day. If they click "get price" button the fourth time during the day, there should be an alert message showing "non-vip users can only check price 3 times per day"

Can we do this directly in frontend using javascripts?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a model that records which user got the price and when:

```py
class Prize(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   # Other fields
```

When the user clicks "get price" you could check in the backend if he has already got 3 prices that day with a simple query like:

```py
can_get_price = Price.objects.filter(creation_date__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)).count() < 3
```

Otherwise if you only want to use the frontend, you could cache the datetimes on which prizes were got. However, this method is easily hackable and does not work with multiple computers/platforms.

Comment: can it be simpler? the price is not fixed. can we make a "count" attribute for each user. Then if user is non-vip and count > 3, reject showing price in the webpage. Then everyday at 0:00 the count value of each user is reset to "0". is it ok to do so?

Comment: @Jack You need to store the prize in the database, how else do you know whether a prize has been got or not? If you save prizes in the database saving an additional value to determine how many prizes were taken is inefficient and repetitive (since this information is already in the database and you can write a simple query), plus to reset the value you would have to use cron increasing the complexity. But if you really want to proceed this way add a numeric field to your user model, each time a prize is get do a post request that increments its value and each day reset the value with cron